# Javascript setTimeout with google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, settimeout

Ok, My page gets some markers from a database via JSON and places them on a google maps map. It works ok, but the problem is to show this markers one by one with a small lag, and not all at the same time. As the google maps API, im trying to use setTimeout() method... with no further success. ¿Is it incompatible with json response?

Here it is the code:

This function retrieve all markers data from the db and works fine.

```
function cargarsonidos(cuales)
{      
 $.getJSON("automatizar1.php",{que:cuales},function(json)
        {
          marcadores(json);          
        });
}
```

Response example:

```
[{"id_marcador":"2","lat_marcador":"42.9912","long_marcador":"-7.54505","titulo_marcador":"Example data","tipo_marcador":"Example data","nombre_mp3":"example.mp3","dia":"no","descripcion":"Example data","url_video":"NO","video":"NO"}]
```

And now the function who creates the markers, infowindows and places into map

```
var id="";
function marcadores(json)
 {

          $.each(json,function(index,value)
          { 

        id ="a"+json[index].id_marcador;
                var popid="pop"+json[index].id_marcador;
                var lat=json[index].lat_marcador;
                var long=json[index].long_marcador;
                var titulo=json[index].titulo_marcador;
                var icono=json[index].tipo_marcador;
                var mp3=json[index].nombre_mp3;
                var pagina=json[index].id_marcador;
                var descripcion=json[index].descripcion;
                var url_video=json[index].url_video;
                var video=json[index].video;

        id = new google.maps.Marker(
                {

                  position: new google.maps.LatLng (lat, long),
                  map: map,
                  title: titulo,
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  icon: 'iconos/'+icono+'.png'
                });
```

> setTimeout(function(){markersArray.push(id);}, 200);

```
                if (video === 'SI')
                {
                       popid = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                  {

                       content:'<h3>'+titulo+'</h3><br /><iframe width="420" height="315" src="'+url_video+'"       frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><div id="cambiar"><a href="paginas/contenido.php?sonido='+pagina+'" onMouseOver="mouse_in();" onMouseOut="mouse_out();"><br /><img src="imagenes/datos.png"></a></div>'

                         });
                }   

                google.maps.event.addListener(id,'click', function(){popid.open(map,id);});     

          }); 
}
```

Everything works fine, but there is no delay between each marker ¿why?

Comment: increase your timeout interval - 200 is tiny

Comment: and you probably want the delay between markers not all from the time the loop executes (perhaps 200 times the marker "number")

Comment: javascipt dont waits on setTimeout in a loop.. If you didnt solve this problem ı will write a script for you! Are you here?

Comment: Yeah Mehmet, im here!

Comment: Rachel Gallen, even with bigger intervals, it still without work, :( i think the problem is the each ignores the setTimeout method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using setTimeout in a loop. This is wrong.

Try this;

```
var index = 0;
function CreateMarker(json) {    
  var id;
  id = "a" + json[index].id_marcador;
  var popid = "pop" + json[index].id_marcador;
  var lat = json[index].lat_marcador;
  var long = json[index].long_marcador;
  var titulo = json[index].titulo_marcador;
  var icono = json[index].tipo_marcador;
  var mp3 = json[index].nombre_mp3;
  var pagina = json[index].id_marcador;
  var descripcion = json[index].descripcion;
  var url_video = json[index].url_video;
  var video = json[index].video;

  markersArray[index] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    map: map,
    title: titulo,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon :'iconos/'+icono+'.png'
  });
  index = index + 1;
  if(index != json.length)
   setTimeout(function() { CreateMarker(json); }, 500); //Recursive
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4 the answer Mehmet. It works but only for the first marker!

Comment: I added a for loop in your code, now all markers are displayed... but without the time out!

Comment: no dont use for loop it isnt necessary. It works for 1 marker because id variable is global.. I take it into setTimout please try this

Comment: Global or local... there is the same in this case. Loop is needed to create and show all markers, your code only create the 1st marker instance with the first json registry :)

Comment: isnt your json variable an array? If it is my code will work.. If it is not just parse it to an array with var jsonarray = JSON.parse(json)

Comment: My json is a nested array with several markers and several parameters for each marker this is the problem!

Comment: I am here man :)  I did it with Recursive... Look my code ı edited. I used recursive with setTimeout

Comment: Tomorrow ill post it, the system dont let me at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have the solution here!
The problem was in the line map:map, i have to put markers at the end of all with the time out

> function marcadores(json)  {
>
> ```
>       $.each(json,function(index,value)
>       {    
>
>             var id ="a"+json[index].id_marcador;
>             var popid="pop"+json[index].id_marcador;
>             var lat=json[index].lat_marcador;
>             var long=json[index].long_marcador;
>             var titulo=json[index].titulo_marcador;
>             var icono=json[index].tipo_marcador;
>             var mp3=json[index].nombre_mp3;
>             var pagina=json[index].id_marcador;
>             var descripcion=json[index].descripcion;
>             var url_video=json[index].url_video;
>             var video=json[index].video;
>
>             id = new google.maps.Marker(
>             {
>               //position: new google.maps.LatLng(json[index].posicion_marcador),
>               position: new google.maps.LatLng (lat, long),
>               //map: map,
>               //title: '"'+json[index].titulo_marcador+'"',
>               title: titulo,
>               animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
>
>               icon: 'iconos/'+icono+'.png'
>             });
>             markersArray.push(id);   
>
>  [...]
>
>
>
>       indice=0;     
>       for (var i = 0; i<markersArray.length; i++) 
>       {
>         setTimeout(function() {putMarkers();}, i * 100);
>       }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> function putMarkers()
> {
>   markersArray[indice].setMap(map);
>   indice=indice+1;
> }
> ```